# Python - Modify previous line in console

Tags: python, console

So, if you write something like `"hello"` to the console and then `"\b\b\b\bi"`, you get `hi`. What if I want to do this with multiple lines?

Essentially, I want to be able to output

```
hello
world
```

and then modify the first line; however, it seems that `\b` only moves the cursor left and not back to the line above. How can I do that?

I've tried using `\n`, `\r\f`, and `\f\r` but none of those work.

I think I know why it's not working but I don't know how to make it work.